# Formulating the Twin Prime Conjecture as a Language Recognition problem.

Tags: computational-complexity, formal-languages

I'm trying to figure out how to formulate the Twin Prime Conjecture as a language recognition problem. I've got:

A = {p: p is the largest prime such that p + 2 is prime}
B = {p: p and p+2 are both prime}

I believe A is the correct (but not the only) formulation and that A is not decidable while B is. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that, given a particular prime $p$ which is a twin prime, the question of whether it's the largest such prime is undecidable?

Comment: A is decidable. If the twin prime conjecture is false $A=\emptyset$. If the twin prime conjecture is true the A is a singleton. Either case A is decidable.

Comment: @William: Wouldn't it be the other way around? (i.e. if the twin prime conjecture is false then there is some final twin prime which is the singleton?)

Comment: @Semiclassical That may be true. I may have gotten the conjecture reversed.

Comment: @William: Ok. In any case, I think I disagree with your case of the twin prime conjecture being 'false' (i.e. that there is no $p\in A$.) If the conjecture is false but you don't know that, then you won't be able to determine $A=\emptyset$ because you'll never be able to tell that you've finished. (And that sounds awfully like being undecidable, though I may be confused on the definition.)

Comment: @Semiclassical You agree that A is either empty or a one point set. Certainly an empty set and any finite set is decidable. Hence regardless of the status of the conjecture, A will always be decidable. I can not algorithmic determine the answer to the conjecture, but I still know that a singleton or the empty set is decidable.

Comment: @Semiclassical that's right, I thought A would be one way to formulate the twin prime conjecture as a language decidability problem. I did'nt think B was the right formulation since B is obviously decidable. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think the confusion is to the proper definition of 'decidable' (which I don't rightly know). I would've expected that a proposition isn't decidable if the algorithm I'd use to check it doesn't halt. -@William

Comment: @William I'm using the definition of decidability that states that for A to be decidable, there must be a machine that is able to accept any p that is a member of A and halt, reject any p that is not and halt. There is obviously a machine that can reject any p and halt (once we've found the next higher p). However, if the twin prime conjecture was true, there would be no way for the machine to accept and halt.

Comment: @user137481 First of all forget about the twin prime conjecture. Can you make me a Turing machine that decides the empty set? Sure! Can you make me a Turing machine that decides a one element set? Of course you can! If the twin prime conjecture is false, then $A = \emptyset$. By the above argument $A$ is decidable. Suppose the twin prime conjecture was false. For instance, let say 41 is the largest twin prime. Then $A = \{41\}$. Of course $A$ is decidable. $A$ is always decidable regardless of the conjecture. I just don't know if $A = \emptyset$ or $A = \{41\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property $p\in B$ is decidable, just run a Turing machine which tests $p$ and $p+2$ for being prime numbers. This machine will definitely give you a result (either way) and thus decide whether $p\in B$ or $p\notin B$.

For the other set $A$:

If there are infinitely many twin primes, then $A$ would be empty by definition (i.e. there is no largest twin). If there are only finitely many twin primes, then $A$ would be a singleton, containing the smaller number in the biggest twin primes pair.
By definition the empty set and a particular singleton (any finite set) are decidable, i.e. there are Turing machines which can decide (case by case) if an object is in an explicitly given finite set or not.

The problem here is that your definition of $A$ relies on a possibly undecidable property (i.e. it could be that the twin primes problem itself is undecidable), hence the two cases of whether $A$ is empty or a singleton would not be decidable. But even if the twin problem were decidable, it could be decidable in a non-constructive fashion, meaning that the biggest twin prime would not be given explicitly (and neither would there be an upper bound on the biggest twin prime) and then the unique element in the set $A$ would not be known (or computable from the knowledge about the cardinality of existing twin primes alone).

Comment: So it sounds like it indeed comes down to the definition of decidable. If it meant: "Can I build a machine to look for things in $A$ that I know will halt?" then $A$ is only decidable if the conjecture is false. But if it means: "If I somehow had a machine that can return the set $A$, then I'd know whether the conjecture is true" then $A$ is decidable. Evidently, it's the latter.

Comment: @MHS, both you and William are correct. I reviewed the definition of "decidability" and it does not require that we know which machine is a decider for A. We only need to prove there is such a machine. If we define $M_p$ as a machine that accepts an input n if n = p and rejects otherwise, then one of the $M_p$ is a decider for A. We don't need to know which one.